# select2 with acts_as_taggable_on in Rails

Tags: jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, tags, jquery-select2

I'm  trying to use select2 to tokenize my tags. However, I'm having a lot of difficulty in getting it to work. I've tried many things, but nothing seems to work and Googling and plugging in others' solutions hasn't worked for me. What do I need to do to tokenize my tags using select2 and acts_as_taggable_on?
I want users to be able to choose a tag or create it if it doesn't exist.

I'm using Rails 5. I'm using the 'select2-rails' gem.

My model:

```
class Event < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  acts_as_commentable
  acts_as_taggable_on :tags
end
```

My strong params:

```
def event_params
    params.require(:event).permit(:title, :description, :tag_list, tag_lists: [])
end
```

Note: I've also tried "tag_list: []" (singular). I've tried without "tag list: []" as well. When I remove ":tag_list", none of the tags are persisted to the database.

My view:

```
<%= form_for @event do |f| %>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :title %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :text %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :description %>
  </p>

  <p>
  <%= f.label :tag_list, "Tags" %><br>
  <%= f.text_field :tag_list %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>

<% end %>
```

Note: I've tried a few things here, but this is where I'm at currently.

My js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require select2
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
//= require bootstrap
```

My stylesheets:

```
/*
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 *= require select2
 */
```

Things I've tried in events.coffee:

```
$ ->
  $('#event_tag_list').select2 tags: []
  return

$('#event_tag_list').select2
  tags: true
  tokenSeparators: [',',' ']
```

Note: I've tried a few more things, but this is what I worked with the most.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thought I would answer this in case anyone comes up against a similar issue. It has to do with the way Rails 5 and Turbolinks works. After browsing through RailsGuides, I found out that the issue was that Turbolinks overrides the normal page loading process. I switched the gem to Bootstrap-Tokenfield, but the principle is the same. This is how I fixed my javascript:

```js
$(document).on "turbolinks:load", ->
 $('#event_tag_list').tokenfield();
```

My strong params:

```
def event_params
    params.require(:event).permit(:title, :description, :tag_list)
end
```

My form:

```
  <p>
    <%= f.label :tag_list, "Tags" %> <br>
    <%= f.text_field :tag_list, value: f.object.tag_list.to_s %>
  </p>
```

RailsGuides explanation: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#how-turbolinks-works

Comment: Hi Sorry, it's a bit of time since you posted but I have a similar issue and just cannot get it working in Rails 5. I'm using this tutorial - https://rcode5.wordpress.com/2013/03/07/acts_as_taggable_on-select2-super-easy-tags-in-rails/ and I feel js and jquery codes just give a hassle maybe as you said the Turbolinks issue. What is 'tokenfield' as it cannot resolve?